# Google Map display using Php is not working

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I wrote a code for getting latitude and longitude values from database and displaying it in map.

This code works in Linux(Ubuntu) but it is not displaying Google map when i run it in windows. Please help me to find the solution.

View Source Information :

```
   <?
     $dbname            ='test'; //Name of the database
     $dbuser            =''; //Username for the db
     $dbpass            =''; //Password for the db
     $dbserver          ='localhost'; //Name of the mysql server

     $dbcnx = mysql_connect ("$dbserver", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
     mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die(mysql_error());
     ?>
     <html>
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
     <style type="text/css">
      body { font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial; }
     #map { width: 350px; height: 300px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
     </style>
     <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"    type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">

     var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
     new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
     new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
     var center = null;
      var map = null;
     var currentPopup;
     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
     function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
     var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
     bounds.extend(pt);
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: pt,
     icon: icon,
     map: map
     });
    var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: info,
    maxWidth: 300
    });

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
   if (currentPopup != null) {
   currentPopup.close();
   currentPopup = null;
   }
    popup.open(map, marker);
    currentPopup = popup;
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
   map.panTo(center);
     currentPopup = null;
   });
     }
   function initMap() {
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    zoom: 14,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
   style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
     },
    navigationControl: true,
    navigationControlOptions: {
   style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
   }
   });



   <?
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM manu");
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

   $lat=$row['lat'];
   $lon=$row['lon'];

  echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon);\n");
   }
  ?>
  center = bounds.getCenter();
  map.fitBounds(bounds);



  }
   </script>
   </head>
    <body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
    <div id="map"></div>
   </html>
```

Comment: Could you also add the output code? (the rendered page that this script generates)

Comment: I am not getting any error.. It works fine in Ubuntu and it displays the location with markers. But it is not working in windows

Comment: It's not an operating system issue, more likely a small javascript error that one browser is ignoring and another is not.  paste the output of 'View Source' for more help.

Comment: @shapeshifter Please see my question. I have added the view source information.

Comment: Why is there php source in your html source?  Is your file a .php file?  Or not being parsed by apache?

Comment: @shapeshifter my file name is mapfinal.php .

Comment: What is the url you are accessing in your browser?

Comment: @shapeshifter localhost/mapfinal.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`You should probably follow below link in order to find solution`

[Google map is not displayed using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720383/google-map-is-not-displayed-using-php)

this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Just echoing addMarkers(... isn't going to call it.

Wrap those function calls in $(document).ready()

```
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()

$(document).ready(function() {
<?
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM manu");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $name=$row['name'];
    $lat=$row['lat'];
    $lon=$row['lon'];
    $desc=$row['desc'];
    echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<b>$name</b><br/>$desc');\n");
  }
  ?>
  center = bounds.getCenter();
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

Comment: he has 'body onload="initMap()"'

Comment: Ah right, didn't catch that.  Hard to read with no indentation.

Comment: I am not getting any error msg when I run this code by giving the address in address bar it is just displaying a plain page.

Comment: Nothing in the browsers console?  Nothing in your apache error log?

Comment: @user1844654, it would be helpful if you show us some of the source code that this generates on the page you are viewing. For example, show us how the addMarker commands end up after they are output.

Comment: [Wed Dec 05 11:31:20 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
[Wed Dec 05 11:31:23 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico                                                                      This is what I am getting in error log

Comment: oh your favicon isn't found.

Comment: Call the police.....or just paste the output from 'View Source' like everybody is asking for.