# Google map is not displayed using php

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, wamp

I have a php code which gets location information from database (test) and table name manu which is created using the phpmyadmin in wamp and display those locations on map using markers. Location details in the sense latitude and longitude value.

**UPDATED**

```
<?
$dbname            ='test'; //Name of the database
$dbuser            =''; //Username for the db
$dbpass            =''; //Password for the db
$dbserver          ='localhost'; //Name of the mysql server

$dbcnx = mysql_connect ("$dbserver", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die(mysql_error());
 ?>


 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <style type="text/css">
  body { font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial; }
 #map { width: 350px; height: 300px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
 </style>
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"        type="text/javascript" ></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
  new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
  var center = null;
  var map = null;
  var currentPopup;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
  var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  bounds.extend(pt);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: pt,
  icon: icon,
  map: map
  });
  var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: info,
  maxWidth: 300
  });

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
 if (currentPopup != null) {
   currentPopup.close();
  currentPopup = null;
  }
   popup.open(map, marker);
  currentPopup = popup;
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
 map.panTo(center);
  currentPopup = null;
 });
 }
 function initMap() {
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
  zoom: 14,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
  style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
  },
  navigationControl: true,
  navigationControlOptions: {
  style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
  }
   });


 $.getJSON('googlescript.php', function(items)
 {
 for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) 
 {
 (function(item) 
 {
 addMarker(item.lat, item.long, item.name + ' ' + item.desc);
 })(items[i]);
 }

 });


 center = bounds.getCenter();
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
 }

  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
   <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
   </html>
```

googlescript.php file code :

```
   <?php

   $dbname            ='test'; //Name of the database
   $dbuser            =''; //Username for the db
   $dbpass            =''; //Password for the db
   $dbserver          ='localhost'; //Name of the mysql server
   $tbl_name          ='manu';

   $dbcnx = mysql_connect ("$dbserver", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
   mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die(mysql_error());

   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM manu")or die(mysql_error());

   header('Content-Type: application/json');

   $rows = array();
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
   {
    $rows[] = $row;
   }
  echo json_encode($rows);
  exit;
   ?>
```

Comment: have u check for if there is any error? use mozila addon firebug to check it.

Comment: [Wed Dec 05 15:14:39 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
[Wed Dec 05 15:29:03 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
[Wed Dec 05 15:29:03 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico                                            This is what I am getting in apache error log

Comment: try to check in firebug..i was facing same problem before....even if there is missing any file or error in other code google map wont be load so try to find error else if no error in here..

Comment: @DipeshParmar  am new to this can you pls tell me how to do it.

Comment: okay, u must have firefox mozila right.? okay now search for firebug and install it in firefox mozila..then check if there's error show in console... dont worry u will see bug icon just click it firebug window will shows up and just click on console and enable it..do it then tell us what error firebug shows..

Comment: @DipeshParmar I did what you said.. There is no error in the error log and also map is not displaying

Comment: Actual error is in the php code where u define echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon);\n"); remove this php block map will load...why u add this php block here.

Comment: @DipeshParmar I am trying to get the latitude and longitude values stores in database table(manu). For that only I have added that part of php code there.

Comment: that code actually isnt being rendered properly..let me know what fields are you using in database table.?

Comment: Fields in my database table                                                  1.id                                                                        2.lat                                                                       3.lon                                                                         where lat and lon field is latitude nad longitude values

Comment: create table manu(id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,lat text NOT NULL,lon text NOT NULL);                                                 This is my DB query

Comment: working on ur problem its nearly done once finish i will post it here there is minor code u will need to add...hang on for while bro.

Comment: Check for errors in your browser’s web inspector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Html Page

```
body onload="initMap()" //you forget to close it.

div id="map"
```

Made below change in html file.

`script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"    type="text/javascript"
script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"
script type="text/javascript">
    var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
    new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
    var center = null;
    var map = null;
    var currentPopup;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    function addMarker(lat, lng, info)
    {
        var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        bounds.extend(pt);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            position: pt,
            icon: icon,
            map: map
        });
        var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
        {
            content: info,
            maxWidth: 300
        });`

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function()
    {
        if (currentPopup != null)
        {
            currentPopup.close();
            currentPopup = null;
        }
        popup.open(map, marker);
        currentPopup = popup;
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function()
    {
        map.panTo(center);
        currentPopup = null;
    });
}
```

function initMap()
{
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeControlOptions:
        {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
        },
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions:
        {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    });

```
// getjson code goes here which is as below because i was unable to format it here so i wrote it downward.

center = bounds.getCenter();
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

}
/script>

`$.getJSON('googlescript.php', function(items)

    {

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) 
{

            (function(item) 
{

                addMarker(item.lat, item.long, item.name + ' ' + item.desc);

            })(items[i]);

        }


   });`

I have used `$.getJSON('googlescript.php',` so you need to create a `googlescript.php` file and paste below code in it.



`$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM manu")or die(mysql_error());

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
exit;


?>`

Now check it in action and I'm sure you will get result that you wanted.
Do not forget to change jquery path and change database connection setting and please place jquery path proper.

Comment: Thanks let me try and will accept your answer if it works.. Thanks again

Comment: hey keep in mind about variable u have used lon where as i used long for longitude so change it in getJson accordingly.. and hey you are always welcome.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience i was unable to format GetJson code so i wrote it downside of js put getjson code by replacing comment inside initMap function...have u tried it..it will work cause i got that running with info window content.

Comment: "Change jquery path and change database connection". What does it mean ?

Comment: its means i have used jquery javascript lib to do this task...and database connection change means change localhost and root and database name and etc...have u used jquery before? are u aware of jquery? if not then try it now its very powerful js lib.

Comment: I am able to see only a plain map. I am not getting any marker which points to the location using latitude and longitude values

Comment: can u share ur code.. or provide me ur email so i can mail u code.

Comment: try to zoom out map may be marker which is set is outside the display area.

Comment: i have sent u mail please do check it, i have also send u database table sql file run it and tell me if its work or not.

Comment: ur always welcome..what u were doing wrong bro..share us ur code so other will get help...Thanx

Comment: Ya i will share it. what i did is i forgot to add name and desc column in my database.